# openni_launch crashes with "Failed to set USB interface"

Tags: kinect, openni, asus-xtion-pro-live, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and ROS Groovy. My problem is that my new Asus laptop only has the usb 3.0 ports. This causes a couple of issues with running `openni_launch` command with ASUS Xtion.

The errors were as follows:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.8-0quantal-20130326-0647/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Failed to set USB interface!

[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 18616, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/olga/.ros/log/4920e3d2-99e4-11e2-8532-08606e0b1d34/camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/olga/.ros/log/4920e3d2-99e4-11e2-8532-08606e0b1d34/camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
```

It throws another bunch of errors after a couple of seconds, stating that other processes were not able to start properly, but I guess they are not really relevant here. Though I can of course attach them if needed.

Now, I have already done some digging. I have seen [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/55201/using-ros-with-kinect-failed-to-set-usb-interface/) post and did everything stated there, but this didn't help. I have also seen another post [on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/openni-dev/LZpcyCfh9UE), but it didn't help either. And there was another ROS question in which they say I had to either apply a kernel patch or update a kernel, which I did with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea of how can this be fixed? Or any advices from those able to run kinect on the usb 3.0.
It really sucks having a new i7 laptop and not being able to run the camera on the machine.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59632/openni_launch-crashes-with-%22failed-to-set-usb-interface%22/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-21**:
@nios I have faced this issue in both Fuerte and Groovy while working with ASUS Xtion Pro Live, it is pathetic ! I had to move to Electric to make everything work fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding the USB3 issue, I recently came across this:

[ASUS USB3 hotfix](http://reconstructme.net/2012/10/13/asus-xtion-usb-3-0-hotfix/)

I have not tested it, but it might be worth a shot.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2013-04-27**:
Thanks, already looking at it. Will post in this thread if something works out.

**Comment by [AnSooooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3647/ansooooo/) on 2013-07-30**:
Hi, didn't you find any solution ? I'm facing the exact same issue... Thx !